# Bower update return me invalid-meta The "name" is recommended to be lowercase, can contain digits, dots, dashes

Tags: bower, package-managers

I've tried to remove my installed last package that make my bower like that. But still no luck.
Looks like when I'm install my last package it I mistakenly paste an tab character:

```
bower install               angular-input-stars-directive
```

Now every time I bower update it always return me this error even on my other project:

> bower invalid-meta The "name" is recommended to be lowercase, can contain digits, dots, dashes

I've tried `bower cache clean` and reinstall the bower but still no luck.
Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Check inside your `bower.json`.

```
{
    "name": "package NAME",
    ...
}
```

replace all uppercase characters for `name` property to lowercase. And replace "space" character with either `-` (minus) or `_` (underscore).

```
{
    "name": "package-name",
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks. my package name is Studio Ss. I change it to studio-ss. now it not returning me any error.

Comment: Its not returning an error as ENOGIT, bower ENOGIT        git is not installed or not in the PATH.

Answer (score 21):

You can also use the force option :

```
bower install --verbose --force
```

Answer (score 0):

It is just a warning from bower. In `bower.json`, you just need to update the "name" value to lowercase and without a space. The name can contain dot `.`, hyphen `-`, underscore `_` and digits ie, `your-package1-name`.

```
{
  "name": "your-package1-name",
  // your dependencies
}
```